# how to send an integer to html page while using Express.js routing

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, express-router

I have the following code in Express which redirects to views/index.html page. Now I also want to send some integers to index.html as soon as some function is executed in this code. Whats the fastest way to do this?

```
const app = express()

var path = __dirname + '/views/'

var router = express.Router()

app.use('/',router)

router.get('/',function(req,res)
{
    res.sendFile(path+'index.html')
}
)

app.listen(3000)
```

Comment: `index.html` has to load some JavaScript that asks the server for the values.

Comment: What do you mean by "send to index.html"? Do you want to update the page dynamically or just fill some values to placeholders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I would use an "ejs" file.
Install:
`npm install ejs --save`
Then in your index.js change your code to:

```js
const app = express()

app.set('view engine', 'ejs'); //support ejs files

app.get('/',function(req,res) {
    res.render('index.ejs', {varableName: varablePath}) //make sure your index.ejs is in your "views" folder
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Then in your new **ejs** file use the line: `<%= varableName %>` to import your variables across files

Comment: Thank you. The variable prints nicely and I am also able to log it on console but when I try to supply it to a javascript function present inside index.ejs it always give me zero or undefined. how can I get rid of that? TIA

Answer (score 0):

You need to use templating engines like EJS/Jade to do this:

1. First of all, add it to project, by running the below command:

   npm install ejs --save
2. Convert the html pages to ejs pages.
3. Use the below line in the express server app:

   app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
4. Send the javascript variables using render method. For example:

   res.render('index', {title: "Main Page", counter: 1 });
5. Now, in the **index.ejs** file read the value as below wherever required

   Counter: <%= counter %>,

Comment: Thank you. I want to use counter variable in a javascript function in index.ejs file but counter variable is undefined. how can I get rid of this problem? TIA

Comment: You are most welcome. Follow the above steps mentioned properly it will resolve the issue.